# Как совместить телеграм-канал и бота написанного на Python 3

Tags: python, база-данных, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

В общем у меня есть канал в телеге.
И отдельно созданный бот на основе библиотеки `telebot`
Как соеденить эти два объекта?

Если кто не понял - вот человек подписывается на канал. Боту нужно поприветствовать человека, спросить что он слушает, и описать, какие еще есть у бота функции. Далее нажав на кнопку "Next", чат должен очиститься, а пользователя перекинуть в общий чат.

Как это сделать?

Comment: В настройках BotFather дайте возможность боту работать в каналах (там довольно не очевидно, та настройка которая отвечает за каналы должна быть False). После этого добавте вашего бота на канал, как админа. Теперь бот будет обрабатывать сообщения, которые пришли в ваш канал.

Comment: А как это сделать? 
Добавить канал бота в паблик?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `content_types=['new_chat_members']`, [отсюда](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/issues/532#issuecomment-404019969), для того чтобы приветствовать новых участников:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['new_chat_members'])
def welcome_new_member(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'добро пожаловать в чат')
```

после задавайте вопрос, отлавливайте ответ и отправляйте ссылку на группу хоть в виде inline кнопки, хоть ссылкой.

> если вы покажите пример кода, даже с ошибками, помочь вам будет проще.

Answer (score 0):

1) Бот не может первым писать пользователю в силу ограничений со стороны Telegram.
2) Bot-api не позволяет узнавать, кто подписался на канал, это закрытая информация. Можно лишь проверить присутствие пользователя в канале.

Можно попытаться поделать что-то с user-api (смотреть в сторону telethon или pyrogram), так как до 200 (не уверен, но вроде именно это число) подписчиков администратор видит список подписчиков и в логе действий видно каждую подписку и отписку.